# Why isn't Helvetica Neue rendering properly?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I installed some new Helvetica variations the other day and since then Helvetica Neue isn't rendering how it should (in Chrome or Firefox).

I tried deleting all the Helvetica fonts and installing them again but they're still not rendering properly.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Some letters appear to be taller than others?

The font should be: normal 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue","HelveticaNeue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

Comment: What's the operating system?

Comment: @and31415 I guess it is a common issue on windows and mac.

Answer (score 13):

I assume you are running on Windows, since Mac users have no need to install Helvetica Neue.

This font does not normally exist on Windows and is replaced by Arial.
Installing any flavor of Helvetica is somewhat tricky, since it is rather commonly used
in CSS style-sheets, so can be picked up by the browser even in cases where Arial
is better, to mess-up font rendering in the browser.

There are several implementations/flavors of the Helvetica Neue font.
Some excel at large font-sizes but give poor results for normal sizes.
I have heard that [this one](http://crossgraphicideas.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/helvetica-neue-font-free-download-complete-family/) gives good results, but have not used it personally.

Chrome allows you to provide your own custom CSS changes that overrides the website CSS. 
To find the custom CSS file, close Chrome and go to the folder :

```
%AppData%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css
```

and open the file `Custom.css` in your favourite text editor.

To use Arial instead of Helvetica, paste-in the following lines:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Light'; src: local('Arial'); }
```

You could also use the Chrome extension [Change Font Family Style](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-font-family-style/aabledekpjmoghdjnpnhfkfpmjifklpb)
to force using Arial instead of Helvetica.

**EDIT**

It has been noted that
[user stylesheet (Custom.css) support has been removed from Chrome](https://codereview.chromium.org/66383005/)
since [November 2013](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=161671&view=revision), which explains why the usual solution doesn't
work any more.

Your remaining options as I see them are :

1. Use the extension Change Font Family Style.
2. Totally delete Helvetica from Windows so to force Chrome to use Arial
3. Change to another browser.

To completely delete Helvetica, do the following :

1. Go to Start > Control Panel > Fonts, select the fonts, then on the File menu click Delete ([source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/install-or-uninstall-fonts)).
2. Delete the fonts cache file `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\GDIPFONTCACHEV1.DAT` and reboot.
3. Only if required, search the registry for "helvetica" and delete (very carefully), then reboot.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Bounty's reason "_The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes_". I actually was using the solution you have provided, but after Chrome's latest update, they stopped working.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Helvetica and letting Chrome default back to Arial? You might also try the extension.

Comment: I have restored default fonts, yet no dice. I prefer not to use extensions.

Comment: Even if you have deleted the fonts, they might still exist in the fonts cache. To empty it, delete the file `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\GDIPFONTCACHEV1.DAT` and reboot.

Comment: No changes whatsoever. Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: Strange: Once you have deleted Helvetica completely it can't exist any more, unless it's built-in into Chrome. Could you try the extension, just to see if it works?

Comment: You could also see if cleartype is not turned off.

Comment: The extension fixes it, however, I still prefer not to use any extension. Thanks +1

Comment: I wanted this extension in order to check if the helvetica font still exists on your computer. So it seems that helvetica was not totally removed. I suggest (1) Use the developer tools of your browser to find out which rules for other variants of helvetica are missing in Custom.css, (2) Remove all variants of helvetica as described in [article1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/install-or-uninstall-fonts) and [article2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314960) and for good measures and only if required search (carefully) the registry for "helvetica".

Comment: The solution stopped working because [user stylesheet (Custom.css) support has been removed from Chrome](https://codereview.chromium.org/66383005/ "Chromium Issue 66383005").

Comment: `The solution stopped working because user stylesheet (Custom.css) support has been removed from Chrome.` Wow!!! This is yet another example of the ****** Google devs being ****** fascists and trying to control and limit users. I *love**d*** Chrome when it first came out, but Google has turned it into a worthless pile of trash. This is the last straw! I am definitely jumping ship now; there is no hope left for Chrome. @BrianNixon, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @BrianNixon: Unbelievable! I modified my answer to include this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So I had this issue today and stumbled on answer to a similar question on quora. This fixed it for me faster:

1. Install the extension [Force Custom Fonts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E5%BC%BA%E5%88%B6%E7%BD%91%E9%A1%B5%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%87%AA%E5%AE%9A%E4%B9%89%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93/hckjchjpkmbihoocajjpjajkggbccgee?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)
2. Go to the extension settings in chrome://extensions
3. Next to the Substitute Fonts menu, click the + icon to add a substitute font.
4. Select **Helvetica Neue** using the drop down in the first box and **Arial** in the second drop down next to it.
5. Save your preferences, refresh any pages that had the issue, profit!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to install all (or almost all) Helvetica Neue styles. If you have just some in you "Helvetica Neue" subfolder, your Browser will pick these, in my case it was only the Super Slim variante. DL on cdnfonts.com the helvetica-neue-55.font and you are good to go. it's not the browser's fault, it's due to incomplete font packs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I managed to fix it and here's how:

1. Close All Apps
2. Open Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Fonts, Delete The Helvetica font and delete all fonts of helvetica neue, skip if it says "Font in use"
3. Open Regedit, Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes and delete "helvetica"
4. Restart your computer
5. Now delete all fonts of helvetica neue that said "Font in use" earlier in Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Fonts
   That's it!